# "Stack Overflow Isn’t Very Welcoming" - sure, but you could say that for quite a few SE sites!

Tags: discussion

I am very... *welcoming*... of "[Stack Overflow Isn’t Very Welcoming. It’s Time for That to Change.](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/)"

Reading the post, I'm wondering if the implication is that problems will be sorted out on SO and also (perhaps later) on other SE sites where similar issues exist - or that problems will be sorted out on SO, and none of the other sites matter?

I'm asking partly because there are other sites that need to tidy their act up in the ways mentioned in the post, but also because I think some other SE sites might have unique and useful perspectives on this - and hey, (despite the title of this question) some sites do actually manage to be a bit nicer than SO already, at least in my experience.

Edit: There is a footnote - *This post focuses on Stack Overflow, but most of it applies to the broader Stack Exchange network as well.*. But... that leaves me wondering the same things really. Which bits don't apply? is there the same scope for contributing to this as a non-SO user? Is this something we should be discussing *now* on non-SO site metas, for example? *Why* are other sites mentioned only in a footnote?

Comment: For me the main issue is that if this is an SO problem, why has it been pushed out site-wide on the blog? If it's supposed to be a wake-up call for the whole estate, why the emphasis on SO?

Comment: The first foot note at the bottom of the blog post reads *¹ This post focuses on Stack Overflow, but most of it applies to the broader Stack Exchange network as well.*

Comment: @Catija well spotted :) but I'm still left wondering... Which bits don't apply? is there the same scope for contributing to this as a non-SO user? Is this something we should be discussing on non-SO site metas, for example? Why are other sites mentioned only in  a footnote?

Comment: @topomorto The answer to the latter is because the other sites, combined, are just that: a usually-overlooked footnote under StackOverflow.

Comment: The 1-minute quiz includes options related to "other Stack Exchange sites", so I think that being open to participation would still be welcome. Even if it's not considered in the first round, they may reach out later if they broaden their research.

Comment: @bro ... which wouldn't be a *great* start if inclusion is the aim!

Comment: I find it very strange that SE claims to care about friendliness: all its policies and reward mechanisms are designed to keep this a "clean" Q&A site, that appears on top of search results. They don't care about communities or open discussion. To me, this blog post reads like SJW speech, and not like an honest attempt to make the site more friendly to its users.

Comment: @BlenderBender The goal is to make Stack Overflow a more friendly Q&A site, not to turn it into something it was never meant to be.

Comment: You can't have your cake and eat it: keeping SO "clean" requires policing, and with policing you get bullying. Moreover, the more junk a certain subexchange attracts, the more aggressive mods will be.

Comment: @BlenderBender There's plenty of space between an anything-goes commune and an authoritarian dictatorship for SE to find a workable middle ground. There hopefully should be ways of encouraging (new) users to maintain quality without resorting to effectively smacking their fingers with a ruler whenever they step slightly out of line. -- P.S. bullying isn't "clean". If you want a "clean" SO, the people doing the policing should police the bullies just as much as the newbies. Doubly so if the bullies are the inmates running the asylum.

Comment: @BlenderBender You can enforce rules without bullying.  Keep your [focus on the content, not the person](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/365888/538247).

Comment: @Troyen If you think that, you're deceiving yourself. You cannot have policing without bullying (unless you replace people by programs (that would have to be written by programs (which would have to be written by programs ...)). The only thing you can hope is to keep it to an acceptable minimum. But, I don't see how the folk running SE really care about that anyway. This blog post is full of jargon, and seems nothing more than another case of corporate virtue signaling.

Comment: @BlenderBender I've been a moderator for a site for almost twenty years. There's little value in attacking a person instead of focusing on a problem. A simple "there's not enough information to answer your question" takes far less effort than degrading and insulting someone. Attacking someone doesn't get them to address the issue, they just get defensive (or are the type of person to ignore it). But also remember that hundreds, if not thousands, of other people will read the hostile exchange and come away with a negative view of your community, driving away the people that do search and study.

Comment: The opposite of "don't bully people" isn't "don't have standards".  You can enforce standards without being rude and without being excessively polite.

Comment: @Troyen To bully, you don't have to explicitly attack anyone. Bullying can be as simple as closing a question as off-topic that isn't, or editing it to put words in your mouth. But, the blog post in question doesn't even mention bullying at all (hence, I doubt they'll try to do anything about that). Instead, it advocates that people on SO should be treated based on their sexual, racial and national identity.

Comment: @BlenderBender I think you're reading too much into their examples.  The blog is "too many people experience Stack Overflow as a hostile place."  Then they give some examples of newer coders, women, people of color, etc.  But it's not limited to them.  If you look at the "Getting to the <3 of the problem" section, none of that is specific to a gender, race, or minority.  It's about things that can improve the general tenor of the site. Things that can _also_ help marginalized groups, not _exclusively_ benefit them.

Comment: @Troyen The point is that the post does *not* talk about harassment at all but rather about the supposed existence of people *feeling* upset by undiplomatic statements of facts. In other words, it doesn't talk about problematic behaviour but instead problematizes completely innocuous (albeit maybe insensitive) behaviour. What it talks about isn't a problem, and what's a problem it doesn't talk about.

Answer (score 8):

Clearly no one cares about the rest of us.

The general perception unfriendliness of Server Fault has been a thing for years. I don't remember any massive Twitter thread about it. They're actually a lovely lot once you get to know them.

No one has ever complained about inclusiveness in Super User moderators or the fact we have no female ones.

In short? We're not big enough for people not really engaged in the network to complain about.

We don't need no Twitter whiners telling us we aren't friendly or inclusive. We don't curse the dark. We light fires. We fix the problems we see. We use our [site metas to educate folks](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/12972/can-we-be-nicer-to-folks-whose-english-isnt-that-great). We engage our fellow users. We flag. In short, we make the sites we use what we want it to be through direct, specific action.

While sometimes folk deny it, *communities* form around Stack Exchange sites and as someone *inside* the system and *familiar* with these communities *you* can be part of the effort to make the communities friendlier.

The key is really *watching out for each other*. See something aimed to offend? Have a polite word, and or flag it.

See a user struggling with image uploads? Give a hand

See a post that has a good core, but quite a few spelling mistakes? Fix 'em.

See a question that has information scattered over comments? Roll 'em in. Add a comment like "Comments are meant to be temporary - I've taken the liberty of rolling them into the question.

I've had folks add *substantial* edits to my posts back in the day, and apologise for it. Those edits resulted in my question being better. "Hi, the answer I wanted to post was very similar - so I've taken the liberty of adding additional information that hopefully improves it. If you're unhappy with it, you can choose to roll back". Then upvote the answer so they don't.

In a sense we can make SE better *not* by worrying just about whether $group feels included. We make it better by trying to ensure users have a good experience, and we use *our* knowledge of the system to ease them through the first few posts.

We improve it by helping new users with the experience we have on the site. The best thing we can do for inclusiveness - for new users of *all* sorts is to help guide them.

Comment: [Obligatory Luke Skywalker impression]: _I care!_

Comment: [Obligatory Han Solo impression] *I know!*

Comment: Related: *[Is there a community on Stack Exchange/Stack Overflow sites like there is on Quora?](https://www.quora.com/Is-there-a-community-on-Stack-Exchange-Stack-Overflow-sites-like-there-is-on-Quora/answer/Asheesh-Ranjan)*

Answer (score 4):

It's clearly mentioned in the end of the blog post:

> This post focuses on Stack Overflow, but most of it applies to the broader Stack Exchange network as well.

Comment: As per the comments under the question, that's been spotted, but doesn't really answer my questions...

Comment: @topomorto how so? It does answer the question. Whatever actions they will take will affect the whole SE network, e.g. more strict commet rules.

Comment: See third comment under question....

Comment: @topomorto if the comment is important, then put it in the question, and remove the comment.  You don’t have to indicate you edited your question, that is automatically done for you, and we even know what changed (every single change)

Comment: @Ramhound well, but we don't get notified of edits, so comment like "Please see my edit" is acceptable. Talking in general of course, not this case.

Comment: @Ramhound done (but done 'prominent' style - I don't personally find that the edit history is obvious enough to be fair to responses made pre-edit!)